# transitionend event not firing when you lose focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have attached transitionend event listener to `element` like this:

```
element.addEventListener('transitionend', transitionEnd);
        
function transitionEnd() {
   console.log('transitionEnd fired');
}
```

This is working fine except for one thing: if you lose focus on the page (open another tab or any other window) the event does not fire!!!

Why is this happening and how to fix this?

Comment: Which browser? I can't repro on neither Chrome 93 nor Firefox 92 both on macOs: https://jsfiddle.net/tp9c63yz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `transition-property` property.

> The transitionend event is fired when a CSS transition has completed. In the case where a transition is removed before completion, such as if the `transition-property` is removed or `display` is set to `none`, then the event will not be generated.

Source: [HTMLElement: transitionend event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event)

Comment: In my case the issue was : display is set to none